# accessing methods in inherited traits without miixn

Tags: scala, inheritance

Let say that I have such a case:

```
object Sample02 {

  trait A {
    def lit = "a"
  }

  trait B extends A {
    def add = lit + " + " + lit
  }

  trait C extends A {
    def sub = lit + " - " + lit
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    class BA extends B
    class CA extends C

    val ba = new BA
    val ca = new CA
```

I tried this:

```
    val ls = List(ba, ca)

    for (l <- ls)
      println(l.lit) //here i can't call "add" and "sub" methods
```

How I can have something like this mixin offers?

```
    class BC extends B with C
    val bc = new BC
    bc.lit
    bc.add
    bc.sub
  }
}
```

My concern is if I can avoid the "diamond" inheritance in order to access all methods in three classes - more specifically: without mixin traits but working with classes?

Comment: `List(ba, ca)` is a `List[A]`, but you want to access methods of `B` and `C` if the types within the list have them? Or what?

Comment: I put in List those two instances hopping that I can have acces on their methods through using only one identifier `l` --- so just ignore my `tried` part. I want exacly what the mixin in the end offers: `class BC extends B with C`

Comment: You don't really have a choice here but to mix in both traits. The compiler needs to be able to prove an object is both `B` and `C` to access those methods. Is there any reason you don't want to mix in both traits, like clear conflicts between the two?

Comment: @m-z, one of the reasons is that I have traits that don't override methods with the same names and whenever I mix those traits I need to add another trait on top of them or to go and tell that they override each other and again their overriden order matters. I was hopping to do something with the classes that mix them :(